# Swi-Prolog: No permission to modify static procedure `(;)/2'

Tags: prolog

Hi :) Beginner to Prolog.

I have this code:

```
dog(rex). 
owns(bill,rex). 
animallover(X):-owns(X,Y),dog(Y).
not(beat(X,Y)):-animallover(X),isAnimal(Y). 
beat(bill,tom);beat(bull,tom). 
iscat(tom). 
isAnimal(X):-iscat(X).
```

This yields the error: **No permission to modify static procedure `(;)/2'**

What's wrong there?

Thanks for your help.

```
dog(rex). 
owns(bill,rex). 
animallover(X):-owns(X,Y),dog(Y).
notbeat(X,Y):-animallover(X),isAnimal(Y). 
not(notbeat(bill,tom),notbeat(bull,tom)). 
iscat(tom). 
isAnimal(X):-iscat(X).
```

This solves the problem. But we want to answer the question **"Who hit Tom?"**

That way we can only ask

```
?- nothit(X,tom).
```

and this would yield **bill**.

**So how can we change the code so we can ask who did hit Tom?**

Comment: You need to define first of all what *hit* means in this context. I see information about *is cat* and *is animal* and *dog* and *owns* and even *notbeat*. But what does *hit* mean in terms of these predicates and facts? As it stands, this isn't really making much sense.

Comment: oh i did a mistake. i want to ask `?-notbeat(X,tom)`
But anyways. It sould mean, that X does not beat/hit tom

Comment: What does `not(notbeat(bill,tom),notbeat(bull,tom)).` mean?

Answer (score 4):

The source of your problem is some code that would, in a lesser language, produce a syntax error, but which is syntactically valid but definitely meaningless Prolog.

This part of your code is totally fine:

```
dog(rex). 
owns(bill, rex). 
animallover(X) :- owns(X, Y), dog(Y).
```

Whitespace is free. :)

This is your first problem:

```
not(beat(X,Y)) :- animallover(X), isAnimal(Y).
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to say here because I've been doing Prolog too long. But what you are saying here, stated a little differently, is this:

```
not(Q) :- Q = beat(X, Y), ...
```

In other words, **the procedure you are defining here is `not/1`**, rather than anything to do with `beat/2`. You've got too much stuff in the head. This is kind of an unusual problem for a beginner; usually people with exposure to other languages would make the error of doing too much assignment on the right side of `:-` rather than the left side.

In any case, another way to read `Q :- P` is, "to prove Q, I must first prove P." That's how Prolog thinks about it. Or, "if P, then I can conclude Q." So, you're teaching Prolog how to make a conclusion called `not`, which is almost certainly not what you mean.

Now, on to your next line, where the error occurs:

```
beat(bill, tom); beat(bull, tom).
```

Prolog deals in what are called Horn clauses. The generic Horn clause looks like `Q :- P`, but if you omit `:- P`, what you get is usually called a fact. In this case, the entire thing you have on that line is one fact. The head of that expression turns out to be `;`, so what you've actually written is this:

```
 A ; B :- A = beat(bill, tom), B = beat(bull, tom).
```

You're trying to redefine `;/2` here, in essence, and Prolog is not allowing that because `;` is too important. What you probably meant here was just a period separating two facts: `beat(bill, tom). beat(bull, tom).`.

I hope this helps get you over the hump.

Comment: I wanted to say, that  "Bill beat Tom or Bull beat Tom". So saying `beat(bill, tom). beat(bull, tom).`does not make much sense here.

Comment: You can't say that outside a predicate or a query.

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
beat(bill,tom);beat(bull,tom).
```

you seem to mean "Bill beat Tom or Bull beat Tom".

But by Prolog's rules you are instead trying to redefine `;`, which isn't allowed, and you can't write "Bill beat Tom or Bull beat Tom" as a fact.

Comment: But how else do I but it then?